# Got facepy.exception (#200) when trying to parse posts from facebook group

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, facepy

I'm trying to parse posts from facebook group by Python using facepy to interact with facebook API. I got token with permission for managing posts from groups, but i got exception 'facepy.exceptions.OAuthError: [200] (#200) Requires either admin with granted managed_group pemissions or member using installed app.' . But I am member of that group.

```
from facepy import GraphAPI
graph = GraphAPI('<API_Token>')
print(graph.get('944324092265557/feed'))
```

What's my problem and how to fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I am member of that group

That alone is not enough, the app must also be installed in the group by an admin in this scenario.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v4.0/group/feed#readperms
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/groups-api#app-installation