# How to extract the date of the post from facebook group?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, dom

I want to know how to extract the date of the post from facebook group?
Although I am able to get the date of all the posts except the **first post** because the first post has some gibberish spans & their textContent doesn't makes sense unless they put in order (I thought their classes might have something but no)

What did I tried so far:

I looked up in the DOM of the first post and tried looping over it, the letter I got in random order also I looked up at the div which stores every post's date but apparently its taking approx 16sec so this is a lot of time.
I was expecting to get the date by looping over nodes and by doing textContent but no there were letters but all in random order.
I tried requesting permission for graph-api but apparently its taking too much time.

Also I hover on date of a post I can see a black popup, Any pointer to get the date out of it?
thanks

Comment: Use the API instead of scraping because Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them.

Comment: @WizKid I tried but got error in graph api explorer ""(#200) Requires either admin with granted managed_group pemissions or member
      using installed app.""

also the guy said  "That alone is not enough, the app must also be installed in the group by an admin in this scenario."

here link => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58609119/got-facepy-exception-200-when-trying-to-parse-posts-from-facebook-group

Comment: That is correct. Those are the rules Facebook have set.